# Sql - How to add condition on fields when inserting them into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, insert

I need to insert strings in an sql table, where I have to add condition. For example:

```
SELECT ii.Terminating_Item_Site_ID,
    ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID,
    loc.ServiceAddress,
    loc.ServiceCity,
    loc.ServiceState,
    (ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID + ' - ' + loc.ServiceAddress + ', ' + loc.ServiceCity + ', ' + loc.ServiceState) AS OrigSite
FROM tblItemInventory ii
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceLocation AS loc ON loc1.ServiceLocationID = ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID
```

I need to put a condition when inserting the field `OrigSite`, so if `ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID` or `loc.ServiceAddress` or `loc.ServiceCity` or `loc.ServiceState` is `null`, I don't need to include it so I replace it with ''.

What is happening is that if any of the above fields is `null`, OrigSite is becoming `null` as well.

I have tried to use `WHEN` but I couldn't manage it.
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ii.Terminating_Item_Site_ID,
    coalesce(ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID,''),
    coalesce(loc.ServiceAddress,''),
    coalesce(loc.ServiceCity,''),
    coalesce(loc.ServiceState,''),
    (coalesce(ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID,'') + ' - ' + coalesce(loc.ServiceAddress,'') + ', ' + coalesce(loc.ServiceCity,'') + ', ' + coalesce(loc.ServiceState,'')) AS OrigSite
FROM tblItemInventory ii
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceLocation AS loc ON loc1.ServiceLocationID = ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID
```

ISNULL is a system function that replaces null values with a predifined value.
Colasce is another one like ISNULL But Coalesce is a part of standard sql.
ISNULL is T-sql specific.
Be more standard be more portable.

```
    SELECT ii.Terminating_Item_Site_ID,
    isnull(ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID,''),
    isnull(loc.ServiceAddress,''),
    isnull(loc.ServiceCity,''),
    isnull(loc.ServiceState,''),
    (isnull((ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID + ' - ' + isnull(loc.ServiceAddress,'') + ', ' + isnull(loc.ServiceCity,'') + ', ' + isnull(loc.ServiceState,'')) AS OrigSite
FROM tblItemInventory ii
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceLocation AS loc ON loc1.ServiceLocationID = ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID
```

Comment: this doesnt work, the isnull has to be used on each part of the concatenated string, not on each other column

Comment: In concatenation if one part is null whole concatination become null.so isnull works on whole concatenation.

Comment: yes you can replace the null from the result of concatenation but you still lose the rest of the substrings. If you isnull the substrings you dont lose any data that was present. also, coalecse returns the first not null of the supplied fields so in your example you get either ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID or ' - '

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate string and 1 of the string is null the concatenated result is also null. You can use isnull('string','') on each part to avoid that behavior. Here is the code example:

```
SELECT ii.Terminating_Item_Site_ID,
    ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID,
    loc.ServiceAddress,
    loc.ServiceCity,
    loc.ServiceState,
    (ISNULL(ii.Originating_Item_Site_ID,'') 
         + ' - ' + ISNULL(loc.ServiceAddress,'') 
         + ', ' + ISNULL(loc.ServiceCity,'') 
         + ', ' + ISNULL(loc.ServiceState,'')) AS OrigSite
FROM tblItemInventory ii
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServiceLocation AS loc ON loc1.ServiceLocationID = ii.Originating_Item
```